# libcurl missing libaries after switching from MacPorts to Homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, libcurl, typhoeus

I removed Macports a while ago so now I use Homebrew. 
Now I am trying to use the typhoeus ruby gem wich depends on multicurl.

When I try to execute my rubyscript I get the following Error-Message:

```
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ffi-1.0.11/lib/ffi/library.rb:121:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'libcurl': dlopen(libcurl, 10): image not found. (LoadError) Could not open library 'libcurl.dylib': dlopen(libcurl.dylib, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.dylib   Reason: image not found   from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ffi-1.0.11/lib/ffi/library.rb:88:in `map'     from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ffi-1.0.11/lib/ffi/library.rb:88:in `ffi_lib'     from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus/curl.rb:405:in `<module:Curl>'    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus/curl.rb:6:in `<module:Typhoeus>'  from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus/curl.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'   from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'  from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'  from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/typhoeus-0.4.2/lib/typhoeus.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'  from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'    from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'  from app.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Obviously some files are missing.

When I execute `$ otool -L /usr/local/bin/curl` I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libidn.11.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.5.0)
/opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.1.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.2.0)
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
```

The issue here is that my folder `/opt/local/` doesn't even exist.

- How do i fix the missing links?
- Where do I get the missing files? (libidn.11.dylib, libintl.8.dylib, libssl.1.0.0.dylib, libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib and libz.1.dylib)?

Additional Infos:

- I am using ruby 1.9.3 and Mac OSX 10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have not fully removed MacPorts and its `curl`.

If you haven't already, you will want to follow the guide at http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html, specifically the following:

```
$ sudo rm -rf \
    /opt/local \
    /Applications/DarwinPorts \
    /Applications/MacPorts \
    /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
    /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
    /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
    /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
    ~/.macports
```

After that, you will want to remove curl with `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/curl`.

`curl` and `libcurl` are already included on OS X, but `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH before `/usr/bin`.  So, at some point you probably installed a new version of `curl` with MacPorts that is now left over.

You will thus want to fully purge the `curl` stuff in `/usr/local`.  That may end up being a little tricky, and if you don't have a lot installed with Homebrew, it might be a good idea to fully purge Homebrew and manually clean `/usr/local` before reinstalling Homebrew.

Finally, once `curl` is gone, you will want to remove the gems that were depending on libcurl and reinstall.

All this could have probably been avoided if `curl` was uninstalled with MacPorts before uninstalling MacPorts, but I've never used MacPorts myself, so not 100% on that.

Comment: Fully purging `curl` from the system is likely not safe, not to mention it's likely to get reinstalled during OS updates. Instead, one should alter their `PATH` to change the search order.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not recommending to purge `curl` but to purge the copy of `curl` that MacPorts installed to /usr/local.  OS X comes with `curl` and `libcurl` already and those versions work fine with ruby.  The built-in `curl` is located at `/usr/bin/curl`.  Fully agree with you about not wanting to purge system `curl`.

Comment: Yes but i had no other solution. I had to clean up a lot of stuff but it worked. :)